# Powershell: Recursively delete but exclude non-empty folders with a specific name

Tags: powershell-3.0, administration

I've searched all over, but nothing seems to do exactly what I need..

I have a folder structure like this:

- C:\Test\Job1\attachments\
- C:\Test\Job2\attachments\
- C:\Test\Job3\attachments\

I'd like to delete all files and folders in C:\Test (but not C:\Test itself) *if* their attachment folders are empty. Non-empty attachment directories should be left alone. All other files and folders should be removed.

So, if the only file in the above paths was C:\Test\Job2\attachments\test.txt, the only folders left after my script would be C:\Test\Job2\attachments. The Job1 and Job3 directories would be deleted.

1. To get the ball rolling, I've tried this in order to delete everything but the attachment folders:

   `$TargetFolder = "C:\Test\*"
   get-childitem $TargetFolder -exclude attachments* -recurse |
   remove-item -WhatIf`

...but it seems to completely ignore the -exclude flag

2. This works sort-of, but it gives me prompts that I'd need to say 'no' to for it to work right:

   `Get-ChildItem -Path $TargetFolder -Recurse |
   Select -ExpandProperty FullName |
   Where {$_ -notlike $TargetFolder + "*\attachments\*.*"} |
   sort length -Descending |
   Remove-Item -Force`

...it would be great if the was something that was the opposite of -Force

Answer (score 0):

If you just need it to select "No" for you, did you try using with the flag `Remove-Item -Confirm:$False`?  Also, try `Remove-Item -Force -Recurse` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't troubleshoot pipelines.

Try it this way and re-work into a pipeline if you wish.

```
$TargetFolder = "C:\Test\*"

$FoldersInTargetFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path $TargetFolder | Where {$_.psIsContainer -eq $true} 

ForEach ($folder in $FoldersInTargetFolder) {
    [STRING]$AttachmentsFolder = "$($folder.FullName)\attachments"
    $AttachF = Get-item $AttachmentsFolder

    If ($AttachF.EnumerateFileSystemInfos() | select -First 1) {
        #Found files and/or Folder in \attachments\
        Remove-Item -Path $folder.FullName -Force
    }
}
```